# Pipe a device via USB or wlan

Tags: devices, streaming, netcat, usb-device

I have an Android phone and I want to use some of its onboard device from PC. To be more clear, there is a node in /dev/ and I want to have on PC a file (or named pipe which is accessable as a file) mapped to this node to make a program read/write this file as if the program was executed on phone.

I have heard about netcatting /dev/audio, but I need bidirectional access.